# Intel C++ compiler bug in member function overload resolution involving "using" alias?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-bug, icc

```
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T, T... Is>
struct Bar { };

template<size_t... Is>
using Baz = Bar<size_t, Is...>;

struct Foo {
  template<size_t... Is>
  void NoAlias(Bar<size_t, Is...>) { }

  template<size_t... Is>
  void Alias(Baz<Is...>) { }
};

template<typename T, T... Is>
void foo(Bar<T, Is...>) { }

template<size_t... Is>
void bar(Bar<size_t, Is...>) { }

int main() {
  // All these work fine
  foo(Bar<size_t, 4, 2>());
  foo(Baz<4, 2>());
  bar(Bar<size_t, 4, 2>());
  bar(Baz<4, 2>());
  Foo().NoAlias(Bar<size_t, 4, 2>());
  Foo().NoAlias(Baz<4, 2>());

  // But these two give error on ICPC (ICC) 14.0.2:
  //   no instance of function template "Foo::Alias" matches the argument list
  // Note the only difference between NoAlias and Alias is (not) using the alias
  // for the member function parameter
  Foo().Alias(Bar<size_t, 4, 2>());
  Foo().Alias(Baz<4, 2>());

  return 0;
}
```

ICC 14.0.2 gives error:

```
$ icc -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -pthread -o .scratch{-,.}cpp && ./.scratch-cpp

.scratch.cpp(36): error: no instance of function template "Foo::Alias" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (Bar<size_t, 4UL, 2UL>)
            object type is: Foo
    Foo().Alias(Bar<size_t, 4, 2>());
          ^

.scratch.cpp(37): error: no instance of function template "Foo::Alias" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (Baz<4UL, 2UL>)
            object type is: Foo
    Foo().Alias(Baz<4, 2>());
          ^
```

However, it compiles with both GCC 4.8 and Clang 3.4.2. (Tested on a 64-bit Linux.)

Can anybody who is well acquainted with the C++11 standard confirm this is indeed a bug?

Also, is there an easy preprocessor-based workaround?

Comment: I suggest you ask in the Intel C++ forum at https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is (clearly) well-formed. §14.8.2.5/9 describes how deduction is performed in this case.

> If `P` has a form that contains `<T>` or `<i>`, then each argument `P`<sub>*i*</sub> of the respective template argument list `P` is compared with the corresponding argument `A`<sub>*i*</sub> of the corresponding template argument list of `A`. […]. If `P`<sub>*i*</sub> is a pack expansion, then the pattern of `P`<sub>*i*</sub> is compared with each remaining argument in the template argument list of `A`. Each comparison deduces template arguments for subsequent positions in the template parameter packs expanded by `P`<sub>*i*</sub>.

Moreover, your code is compiling with version 15.0.3 on my machine. Hence upgrading the compiler should fix the issue. I can't see another simple workaround.